# Conditional distinct rows in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, distinct

I have a dataframe in which I want to keep all the distinct string entries (i.e. get rid of duplicates) in one column *unless* these entries are short, str_length < 7. I also want to keep all the other columns.

So I have

| string | other columns |
| --- | --- |
| "abc" |  |
| "abc" |  |
| "centauri" |  |
| "centauri" |  |
| "armageddon" |  |
| "armageddon" |  |
| "spaghetti" |  |

Desired output:

| string | other columns |
| --- | --- |
| "abc" |  |
| "abc" |  |
| "centauri" |  |
| "armageddon" |  |
| "spaghetti" |  |

I have tried a variety of dplyr approaches, but nothing works.

```
df <- df %>%
  mutate(len = str_length(string))%>%
  group_by(string, len) %>%
  filter(len >7) %>%
  distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
```

In this example, I am not getting the rows back which I filtered out. But I just want to protect the filtered rows from the distinct function and then get them back into the dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` with `nchar`

```
df1[!(duplicated(df1$string) & nchar(df1$string) > 7), , drop = FALSE]
```

-output

```
#     string
#1        abc
#2        abc
#3   centauri
#5 armageddon
#7  spaghetti
```

---

Or with `filter` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   filter(!(duplicated(string) & nchar(string) > 7))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(string = c("abc", "abc", "centauri", "centauri", 
"armageddon", "armageddon", "spaghetti")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked! I thought it should be really easy, but I couldn't figure it out.

The only other solution that occurred to me right after posting was to introduce a dummy column in which all rows with short strings get a randomly generated number/string.